# Have a textarea with the placeholder in the middle but when I have more rows, the rows grow upwards until reaching the margin

Tags: html, css

I have a textarea, I have the placeholder in the middle but when I start writing more that one row, the text cuts down beacause of the padding. If I remove the padding, the placeholder is not centered.

How can I achived both things?

```
        <div class="container">
          <textarea
            value={body}
            onChange={e => setBody(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="Escribe un mensaje"
            onKeyPress={async event => {
              if (event.key === "Enter") {
                onSave(mutate);
              }
            }}
            required
          />
        </div>

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
}

textarea {
  margin: 0px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 16px;
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.fonts.openSans};
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 16px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: none;
  resize: none;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  border: none;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;

  &::placeholder {
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: light;
  }

  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent;
  }
  ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #ff0000;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to center the placeholder, you don't need padding, simply add this:

```
textarea::placeholder {text-align: center;}
```

However, there are some issues with placeholder, it will work different on different browsers. You can learn more [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/).